# Power of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

In taking the power of a series

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k \right)^n = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k$$

do you know an expression for $c_k$ solely in terms of the coefficients $a_k$?

Comment: The multi-nomial expansion formula?

Comment: What would that be in my notation?

Comment: @Simple Art: how do you do a multinomial expansion on an **infinite** series?

Comment: Monstrous.  I can hardly describe it without giving you [the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Clearly, each $c_k$ depends only on a finite amount of $a_k$, since higher powers will never decrease.

Comment: [This](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-5/hilliker.pdf) may be of interest.

Comment: May I write that as $c_k = \sum_{i_1 + \ldots + i_k = k} {{k} \choose {i_1, \ldots, i_k}} \prod_{s=1}^k a_s$?

Comment: Why would you have that coefficient?Also, $\prod_{s=1}^k a_s$ doesn't seem to depend on the $i_1,\dot,i_n$. Also, The $i_1,\dots,i_n$ should end in a suffix that is not $k$. @Jennifer

Comment: Which coefficient are you referring to?

Comment: Where does $n$ enter into that formula, @Jennifer

Comment: You can also compute the coefficients $c_k$ successively using Taylor series arithmetic, essentially for the cost of one power series multiplication. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1471438/115115 and the there linked wikipedia article or any other references on automatic differentiation.

Answer (score 3):

$c_k$ is the sum of $a_{k_1} a_{k_2} \ldots a_{k_n}$ over all ordered $n$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(k_1, \ldots, k_n)$ whose sum is $k$.

Answer (score 2):

The form you seem to be seeking is $$c_k=\sum_{\substack i_0+i_1+i_2+\cdots+i_k=n\\i_1+2i_2+\cdots+ki_k=k}\binom{n}{i_0,\cdots,i_k}\prod_{j=0}^k a_j^{i_j}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is repeated application of Cauchy Product : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product